# How can I have a table without primary key in Magento?

Tags: magento

In Magento, it is necessary that you create a primary key in order your grid and module to work. But, I don't have primary key in my table and don't want to create it. Is it possible to make my module work properly without primary key?

Magento is giving error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.modulename_id' in 'field list'` as it doesn't find primary key id in the table while displaying grid.

Without auto-increment it can be done with:
`$this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;` in the model. Is there anything like that for primary key as well?

I searched on net without any luck. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you will not use model/collection for this table, you can do this. If not -- you cann't (without rewrites). See newsletter queue and queue_link tables -- there are no model for queue_link table (it has primary key, but you can use your table without it if you will wok in such way), all things are done in queue resource.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to show grid and also insert new records in the table, also I can't alter the table. Can you please help me explaining how and what should I rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

The Magento ORM is setup  in a way which will require you specify a primary field. You should always have primary key anyway, I can't imagine a situation where you would want one as it would no longer be suited to a database...

I would imagine you may want a natural/composite key rather than a surrogate key, but I am not sure if that's what you meant?

Comment: I don't have any key in my table. I want to show grid, but it's throwing error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.modulename_id' in 'field list'`, ofcourse it is expecting primary key id here. Can you help me in resolving this? Thanks for  your answer.